# Resharper formatting issue: if() statement in VS2022 C++ code

Tags: c++, resharper, visual-studio-2022, resharper-c++

I'm working on vs2022 with resharper. And there is a problem with me editing the `if()` in a {}.

```cpp
float example (){
if()
}
```

the moment i tapped the () after if, resharper format the code like this:

```cpp
float example (){ if () }
```

How can i disable this auto-formatting, I just can't the proper settings. It's grateful if someone can help.

I look through the document, but failed to find a proper setting.

Comment: Here's my solution for now.

In vs2022, Tool/Option, then search clang-format, select the second option, only use clang-formatter when choosing.